# how to determine dimension of bases?

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello guys let's say we have 3 vectors $u,v,w$ in  $R^4$. Does bases dimension depends on dimension of subspace? For example in $R^4$ can we have bases which has $\dim=2$ or $\dim=3$? I was confused when I saw dim=3 bases in $R^4$ and then in another page I saw dim=4 bases in  $R^4$. So can we say dimension of bases must be equal or less than subspace? so in this case if we have $R^4$ subspace then dimension of bases can be 1,2,3. SO we just need to select 1 or 2 or 3 independent vectors then it will be bases?

Comment: Your question needs more clarity. Try rewriting it so that it would be clearer as to what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you now it is clear.

Comment: There's no such thing as dimension of the basis. Basis isn't a vector space, but its _span_ is (set of all linear combinations of its elements). You probably meant the _cardinality_ of the basis. Cardinality of the bases equal dimension of your subspaces. One thing that contradicts your goal is that every vector space contains the $0$ vector which can never be an element of a basis. I think your question is a duplicate of every single post on the site regarding the **extension to a basis for the whole space**.

Comment: Or perhaps you meant the dimension of the span of your set of three vectors. That can be any integer from $0$ (achievable only if each vector is the zero vector, so in particular they wouldn't be distinct) to $3$, depending on the choice of vectors.

Comment: Let me give an example to clarify. Subspace V in $R^4$ consists of column vectors for which x1=x2 and x3=3x4.  Question is "determine a basis in this subspace and determine subspace dimension" . In answer-sheet it is written bases which consists of 2 vectors and dimension of subspace is 2. So my question is can we write bases which consists of 3 vectors then dimension of subspace become 3? Or can we write 4 vectors. I thought if vectors in $R^4$ then dimension should be 4 and bases can only contains 4 vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely following your question, but perhaps this might be helpful.  I believe it is more clear to speak about a basis which *spans* a subspace of a given dimension.  If we take $\mathbf{R}^{4}$, it is possible to have subspaces that have dimension 1, 2, 3, or 4.

A subspace of dimension 1 would require a single vector to span it, a subspace of dimension 2 would require 2 linearly independent vectors to span it, etc.  The dimension 1 subspace has a basis consisting of one vector which spans it, and the dimension 2 subspace consists of a basis with two vectors which spans it.

Please note that since we are in $\mathbf{R}^{4}$, each of the vectors mentioned has four components, like $\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix} x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\ x_{3} \\ x_{4} \end{bmatrix}$, but the number of components is not the same as the "dimension" as used when talking about the dimension of subspaces.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much now everything is clear.What about spans and linear dependence. Can we say all independent vector are generating system?